# ‘Daran’ versus ‘dran’ — which one is correct?

Tags: difference, word-choice

I found *daran* in many texts but I found *dran* as well, for example here:

> Ich bin morgens gewöhnlich spät daran.
>   In the morning, I am usually late.

or

> Ich bin morgens gewöhnlich spät dran.
>   In the morning, I am usually late.

and in dictionaries they have the same meaning.

Is there any difference between the two? Is only one of them correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In many cases, *dran* is a short form of *daran.* However, there are also cases in which *dran* **cannot** be replaced by *daran.* Your example is one of them:

> Morgens bin ich immer spät dran. (Correct)
>
> <del>Morgens bin ich immer spät daran.</del> (Incorrect)

This is because there are actually *two* words *dran* which are similar yet distinct. The first is the shortened, colloquial form of the pronominal demonstrative pronoun *daran.* It can always be replaced by the more formal *daran* but also typically by something like *an der/die Sache.*

> Wir bauen neben unser Haus einen Schuppen. Der soll direkt dran anschließen.
> Der soll direkt daran anschließen.
> Der soll direkt an das Haus anschließen.
>
> Diese Veranstaltung geht bis zwölf. Im Anschluss d(a)ran findet die Veranstaltung *Wie wasche ich meinen Mitmenschen den Kopf* im Hörsaal zwei statt.
> Im Anschluss an diese Veranstaltung findet […]

The second case is an adverb *dran* which **cannot** be replaced by *daran* but only occurs in a few set phrases. For example:

> (when playing a board game)
> Wer hat gerade gewürfelt? Bin ich **dran?**
>
> Heute bin ich ausnahmsweise mal früh **dran.** Senile Bettflucht.
>
> Was ist **dran** an den Vorwürfen, dass führende AfD-Politiker »Lügenpresse«-Zeitungen lesen?

Comment: I’m not convinced the last bit is true; While certainly **daran** is indeed pretty much never used in these sentences they are colloquial to begin with. I don’t think this is actually an indicator that they are indeed different words. “dran” still means the same thing as “daran” in fragments like “spät dran”, you just don’t substitute one form for the other in regular usage.